# Determining if a string is a palindrome

Tags: javascript, regex, string, palindrome

I wanted to know where my logic is faulty. A string (`str`) is taken as an argument (the string could be lowercase, uppercase, with commas and periods) and set equal to var `string`. It is then reversed and if it equals the original string then the return value is `true`. If it is not equal a return value of `false` is displayed. Why does it evaluate everything as true?

```
 function palindrome(str) {
     var string =str.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/,/g , '').replace(/./g , '');

     if (string==string.split("").reverse().join("")) {
         return true;
     }
     else{
         return false;
     }      
}

palindrome("nope");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**tl;dr** replace the `.` in your last regex with a `\.` to strip out literal `.`s; right now, you're stripping out *all* characters.

## The Problem

In regex, `.` matches any character (except new lines, `\n`, at least by default). So, this code replaces *any* character:

```
replace(/./g , '')
```

As a result, you're emptying the string. The reverse of an empty string is an empty string, so you always get a returned value of `true`.

## The Solution

To match a literal period, you have to escape the `.` by writing `\.`. So, change that part to

```
replace(/\./g , '')
```

## Some Refactoring to Make Your Code More Awesome

You can also just return the result of your comparison; no need for the `if`/`else` block here. This would make your entire code (formatted for readability):

```
function palindrome(str) {
    var string =str.toLowerCase()
                    .replace(/\s/g, '')
                    .replace(/,/g , '')
                    .replace(/\./g , '');

    return string==string.split("").reverse().join("");
}

palindrome("nope");
```

You can go even further and just strip all non-alphabetical characters, so your code can be even simpler:

```
function palindrome(str) {
    var string =str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]/g, '');

    return string==string.split("").reverse().join("");
}

palindrome("nope");
```

Comment: Okay, that made a lot more sense. Thank you!

Comment: `string.split("").reverse().join("");` be aware this trick works in English and some other languages that use the Latin character set but may fail in languages that use characters that use Unicode character points > 16bits.